# how to list all files starting with

Tags: linux, list

How lists all files in the directory `/usr/bin` with names starting with "g" followed by “o” put the result inside new file under a directory
I'm tried to do this `ls -al go* /usr/bin` but this list all the files without the specified characters

Comment: `ls /usr/bin/g*` &  `ls /usr/bin/o* ?` OR `ls /usr/bin/g*o*` ?

Comment: To put the results in a new file do `ls /usr/bin/go* > somedir/outputfile`

Answer (score 2):

`ls` takes a list of things to list.

`ls -al go* /usr/bin` means "List everything in the current directory starting with `go` and everything in `/usr/bin`".

You need to specify the one thing you want to list:

```
ls -al /usr/bin/go*
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$ ls -al /usr/bin/go*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     7 Apr 25  2017 /usr/bin/gold -> ld.gold
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10304 Feb  7  2013 /usr/bin/gouldtoppm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /usr/bin
ls -al go* > file
```

or if you want to do it in a single command:`ls -al /usr/bin/go* > file`